# Textbox Winforms Autocomplete Custom Source from config file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a config file where there are IP adressed which are used to connect to the server.

Now I want to add these IPs to the textbox AutoCompleteCustomSource on AutoCompletemode - SuggestAppend so that the user can see the ip suggest.

I can add the IPs manually to the AutoCompleteCustomSource but I want to change it always though the config file.

Comment: You will need to write a function that loads the configuration file from disk, parses the entries, and then programmatically append them to the AutoCompleteCustomSource object.

Comment: I use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to parse the entries. Could you explain it How I can append them?

Comment: I suggest to create a Section in `app.config => <configSections>`, e.g., `<section name="IpAddressesSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>`. Create your own, specific settings: `<IpAddressesSettings> </IpAddressesSettings>`. Use `var ipAddrSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("IpAddressesSettings") as NameValueCollection;` to read the section values and retrieve them with `var values = new List<string>(); if (ipAddrSection.HasKeys()) { values.AddRange(ipAddrSection.AllKeys.Select(k => ipAddrSection.Get(k))); }`.

Comment: Now you just need to set the AutoComplete properties:  `textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(values.ToArray());`

Comment: But, you can also use the Project's `Settings`, adding, in the `Application` scope, a `StringCollection` with your values. You can read it with `Properties.Settings.Default`.

Comment: thanks I did it with AutocompletestringCollection and an array to store the variable